# Switching input to instrumental amplifier with an analog mux (ECG, EEG)

Tags: amplifier, analog, biopotential, ecg

I'm trying to find a cost effective method of taking samples of electrical signals of the body (and potentially [plants](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2835954/)).

Can you have one high precision instrumental amplifier and then use an analog mux to read different inputs (different electrodes on the scalp, chest)?

I looked at this mux (CD74HC4067). Is the on resistance a problem?

[image: http://image.prntscr.com/image/100c8ac148e345bd9785fb0f418c6548.png]

Do you have any other suggestions for a cheap EEG device?

Thank you for reading and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For measuring biopotentials cheaply AND easily I would recommend using a dedicated analog front-end eg. [ASD1194](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads1194). One chip + some resistors and capacitors. All muxes, right-leg drive and ADCs are integrated, you just read your data over SPI.

Answer (score 2):

When reading really week analog signals, you'd very much try to avoid additional things in your signal path before you buffer/amplify that signal.

So, no, I don't think your analog multiplexer will do as is – you should have a high-input-impedance amplifier for every channel, and then you can mux all these amplified channels. Or don't – many microcontrollers come with an ADC that you can switch between different channels out of the box, or you just buy a multi-channel ADC.

At any rate, there's a lot of guides online on how to build your own EEG with e.g. an Arduino, a raspberry pi, other microcontrollers, DAQs…